# Python Recursive function to fetch data from dict

Tags: python, recursion

I have created a recursive function to fetch the data from a dictionary.
The dictionary consists of keys and each key has a list of keys and it goes on. So I need to fetch the flatten list of keys when I give a key input.

My Dict :

```
data = {"p": ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"],
        "s1": ["s1s1", "s1s2"],
        "s2": [],
        "s3": [],
        "s4": [],
        "s1s1": [],
        "s1s2": ["s1s2s1"],
        "s1s2s1": []
        }
```

My function :

```
def get_data(key):
    items = data[key]
    if items:
        for key in items:
            items += get_data(key)
    return items
```

when i call `get_data("p")` it returns

```
['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's1s1', 's1s2', 's1s2s1', 's1s2s1']
```

But the expected output is :

```
['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's1s1', 's1s2', 's1s2s1']
```

Thanks in advance for any help ...

Comment: What is `items`?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: @MuthuKumar does the order of the list in which they are present matter?

Comment: @MuthuKumar Please refer to the answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in these lines -

```
for key in items:
    items += get_data(key)
```

Here you are modifying items as you're iterating over it. So in the last iteration, your `items` ends up getting with the same key multiple times; you can add a logging statement to see which key is being used to call `get_data`.

You want to obtain all the new items separately, and then update items after the iteration is done -

```
new_items = []
for key in items:
    new_items += get_data(key)
items += new_items
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code which will help you achieve what you want. The common approach to get a unique collection of items is to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set). Sets are unordered collections of distinct objects. To create a set from any iterable, you can simply pass it to the built-in [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) function. If you later need a real list again, you can similarly pass the set to the [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function.

```
data = {"p": ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"],
        "s1": ["s1s1", "s1s2"],
        "s2": [],
        "s3": [],
        "s4": [],
        "s1s1": [],
        "s1s2": ["s1s2s1"],
        "s1s2s1": []
        }

def get_data(key):
    items = data[key]
    if items:
        for keys in items:
            items += get_data(keys)
    return list(set(items))

print(get_data("p"))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['s3', 's1s1', 's1', 's1s2', 's2', 's1s2s1', 's4']
```

Update: an order-preserving approach is two lines:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
return OrderedDict((x, True) for x in items).keys()
```

replace the `return` line of the given solution with the `return` line of the Update: Solution and you will get an ordered list in return.

**OUTPUT:**

```
odict_keys(['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's1s1', 's1s2', 's1s2s1'])
```

Use `list()` function with the achieved output to get the following list:

```
['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's1s1', 's1s2', 's1s2s1']
```